# fold: outputs only the first character

Tags: bash, array, fold

I am using `fold` to make an array of characters from a string.

```
INPUT=$1
arr=($(fold -w1 <<< "$INPUT"))
echo "$arr"
echo "$arr[@]"
```

I use command `./myProgram 1234` to execute the script.

Expected output: `1 2 3 4`

What I get: `1` and `1[@]`

Comment: `echo "${arr[@]}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly assigned the output to the array, but your de-referencing needs help:

> echo "$arr"

Simply outputs the first element of the array, which is `1`.

> echo "$arr[@]"

Is missing the curly braces that would tell bash that you want to subscript the array; as-is, it's dereferencing `$arr` to the first element, as above, and then printing `[@]`.

Instead, use (for example):

```
printf '%s ' "${arr[@]}"
```

See the [bash manual section on Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) where it says:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators.